# Type of a struct member at compile time

Tags: c, types, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way of knowing the type of a struct member at compile time? Something analogous to `offsetof()`, but for types.

Eg. something like:

```
typedef struct{
  int  b;
  char c;
}a_t;

typeof(a_t,b) a_get_b(void* data){
  return *(typeof(a_t,b)*)(data + offsetof(a_t,b));
}
```

Comment: `data + offsetof(a_t,b)` --> Adding an offset to a `void *` is UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You sure? I just assumed it was always 1 byte per int

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment!  What it said was, if you have C11 then https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897994/2193968 may help.

Comment: étale-cohomology Yes - sure: [C null pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233071/2410359)

Comment: To remind: A quick note about C and `offsetof`: Per C if "a null pointer is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object" and "any two null pointers shall compare equal", then a null pointer is _not_ a pointer to object. Hence, "a postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier" does _not_ designate a member of a structure object. Hence, [`((st *)0)->m`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) violates the semantics of the `->` operator. However, if the `offsetof` was tested, then it _can_ be used. Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499126/1778275.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use `typeof` (which is currently a very common nonstandard C extension slated for inclusion in the next version of the standard), you can apply it to a member obtained from a compound literal as in `typeof((a_t){0}.b)`:

```
typedef struct{ int  b; char c; }a_t;

typeof((a_t){0}.b) a_get_b(void* data){ return (a_t*){data}->b; }
```

(Given a type `a_t`, `(a_t){0}` is a reliable way to get an instance of it. Because of how initialization works in C, the 0 will initialize a deepest first elementary member and elementary types are scalars and therefore 0-initializable.)

As for the obtaining the member from a void pointer pointing to the container, you could do:

```
*(typeof(&(a_t){0}.b)((char*)data + offsetof(a_t,b))
```

but that's just an awfully long-winded way to do:

```
(a_t*){data}->b
```

(which is 100% equivalent to the former as long as the effective type of `data` is indeed `a_t*`).

Comment: Thank you, this exactly the answer I was looking for. (Posting again because someone deleted the previous comment? Who would delete a "thank you" comment?)

Answer (score 1):

Another way it works:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define typeof_element(_struct,el) typeof(((_struct *)(0))->el)

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
}Row;

int main()
{
   typeof_element(Row, a) value_a = 10;
    
   printf("%d\n", value_a);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (other than Jerry Jeremiah's) is:

```
#define struct_get(STRUCT,ELEM) *(typeof(STRUCT.ELEM)*) (STRUCT+offsetof(typeof(STRUCT),ELEM))
```

Comment: `typeof` is not defined by standard C.

Comment: Does this need `({ })`? Should work without it I think.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It does

Comment: @JohnBollinger It will be soon !

Comment: @M.M Is there a `typeof` proposal?

Comment: @pmor yes, search C23

Comment: @M.M I search as "C2x typeof Martin Sebor". Still cannot find the proposal (e.g. PDF).