What in the C standard allows compilers to optimize `(((char *)p - 1) == NULL` to false?
Take the following snippet:
#include <stddef.h>

_Bool
foo(char * p) {
    return (p - 1) == NULL;
}

Both GCC and LLVM optimize the result to false.
What in the standard allows the compilers to assume p was not 1?
Edit:
To clarify, the question I am asking is the one in the above code snippet/godbolt link. The cast in the title was to communicate thay the question was about point arithmetic. Sorry for any confusion.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232894/c-null-pointer-arithmetic - Basically the other direction. A null pointer constant doesn't point at any object, and pointer arithmetic may be assumed to give you a pointer to an object in some array (or the behavior is undefined, so might as well not compare equal to a null pointer constant in that case too).

They could actually make the optimization if it were p - 0 (but they do not).

@EricPostpischil - This might be the fault of us C++ folks and our semantics leaking over http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.1

The title and the question are different: (((char *)p - 1) == NULL versus (p - 1) == NULL. The former would require more exposition due to the additional conversion and consideration of its semantics, including the possibility that p is not a pointer. You should edit the post to clarify which question is being asked.

@EricPostpischil yeah, I just wanted to communicate the gist of "pointer minus one" as opposed to an arbitrary type in the title.

@Noah FYI (perhaps relevant / useful): GCC may compare pointer to one past the end of one array object and pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space unequal.

You are not allowed to use pointer arithmetic to compute a result that would fall outside the bounds of an array (or one-past the last element) or struct
n2310 6.5.6/8 Additive operators

When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the
type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the
array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the
difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions
(P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th
and i − n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to
the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array
object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression
(Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point
to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation
shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined

For example, the following is UB
int array[2];
int* p = array + 5; // out of bounds, undefined behavior

for (p-1) == NULL to be true, you would have to have

p points to the address directly after NULL
p is a pointer into the middle of an array (so subtracting from it is allowed)

These two conditions cannot both be true at the same time. If p points to the address directly after NULL then it would have to be the first element of the array. If p is a pointer to the middle of an array, then the address of the element before *p couldn't be NULL.
Subtracting 1 from p is either undefined behavior, or the result is not NULL and your condition is false. In other words, for any well-behaved program, the result is false, and the compiler doesn't need to handle UB.

Re “You are not allowed…”: You are allowed, but the C standard does not define it. It is important to remember the C standard is not a set of requirements that programmers must obey. It is an open standard that specifies a core language. It was deliberately left open for extensions. C implementations are allowed to extend the language by defining things the standard does not, and programmers are allowed to use them.

@EricPostpischil They obviously mean "In a program without undefined behaviour, you are not allowed..."

@M.M: I know what they meant, but, as I wrote, it is important to remember the C standard is not a set of requirements that programmers must obey. It is an open standard intended to be extended. You could also say “In a program without undefined behavior, you are not allowed to link to a graphics library, and you are not allowed to use network services.” C is nearly useless without using behaviors that the standard does not define. One needs to understand that undefined behaviors may be areas for exploitation, not dangers to avoid.

@EricPostpischil it's not UB to call functions in libraries or the operating system

@M.M: Yes, it is. Nothing in the C standard defines graphics operations or calling functions in other languages. Per the C standard, that makes it undefined behavior as the standard defines that term.

Since this is a language-lawyer question, here is a more formal answer than the others:
Given that p is a pointer, p - 1 is specified by C 2018 6.5.6 paragraphs 7 and 8, which cover subtraction of an integer from a pointer. Paragraph 7 tells us a pointer to a single object acts like a pointer to an array of one element. We do not actually need to consider all the intermediate language in paragraph 8; we merely need to observe:

It defines cases where p points to an element of an array or where p points to just beyond the last element of an array. Notably, it does not define any case where p is null.
Each defined result of those cases is either a pointer to an element of an array or a pointer to just beyond the last element of an array.
The latter cannot occur when subtracting 1; such a pointer can be produced only when subtracting zero from such a pointer or when adding a non-negative amount to a pointer.

Therefore, either p - 1 points to an element of an array or the behavior is not defined.
Thus, if the behavior is defined, p - 1 points to an element of an array, which is an object.
NULL is specified to be a null pointer constant (7.19 3). When compare a null pointer constant to a pointer using ==, 6.5.9 5 tells us “the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer.” This yields a null pointer of the type of p, per 6.3.2.3 4, “Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null pointer of that type.”
Thus, we are comparing p, a pointer to an object, to a null pointer. 6.3.2.3 3 says this is guaranteed to compare unequal: “If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.”
Thus, either (p - 1) == NULL evaluates to false or the behavior is not defined. If the behavior is not defined, a C implementation may treat it as false (or may exhibit any behavior), and thus a compiler may optimize the expression to false.
Supplement
Oddly, it appears (p + 1) == NULL is not guaranteed to evaluate to false (or be undefined). As noted above, p + 1 may produce a pointer to just beyond the end of an array. 6.3.2.3 3 tells us a null pointer is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function, but a pointer to just beyond the end of an array is not necessarily a pointer to any object or function. I do not see anything in the C standard that states it cannot be a null pointer. If it is a null pointer, it will compare equal to NULL.
If so, this is likely unintended, a defect in the C standard.

"I do not see anything in the C standard that states it cannot be a null pointer." 6.5.9
Equality operators p6 says "Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, ... both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately
follow the first array object in the address space." Given above, it would seem odd if it could be, as it's not explicitly mentioned.

Out of curiosity: do you know / remember C implementations where null pointer is not the same as the pointer to memory address 0? The tagged architectures may have tagged pointers. However, are there any C implementations for such tagged architectures that have tagged pointers (where null pointer is not the same as the pointer to memory address 0)?

This stems from two things:

A NULL pointer will compare unequal to any object or function pointer.
Pointer arithmetic can only produce a pointer to a valid object (or just past the last element of an array).

So under the assumption that p is a pointer to a valid object of type char, p - 1 will also be a pointer to a valid object, and since a pointer to a valid object cannot be NULL, the comparison will always be false given that assumption.
The validity of the result of pointer arithmetic is spelled out in section 6.5.6p8 of the C standard:

When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
(where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
operator that is evaluated.

And the semantics of pointer comparison is spelled out in section 6.5.9p6:

Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both
are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and
a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one
past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to
one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the
start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow
the first array object in the address space


Do I understand correctly that in this code call of f2 triggers UB?

@pmor Yes, both f1 and f2 have UB.

Yes, indeed, both f1 and f2 have UB.

In C, a well-defined non-null pointer may only point a valid object, or one past a valid object.
The C Standard describes the process of arithmetic on pointers:

When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

This means that either p points to a valid character in a character array/structure/etc., which is not the first element, meaning before that element, there will be a valid character whose address is not NULL.
Or, you are subtracting 1 from the address of a valid char, but the char is at the start of a memory block so doing so would not produce a valid address. This invokes undefined behavior, because the resulting pointer from the subtraction is not either a valid element of the array or a pointer to 1-past the last element.
In one case, we know that p - 1 is not NULL, and in the other case, p - 1 would invoke undefined behavior. Undefined behavior allows the implementation to behave in arbitrary ways, including ignoring any situations that would have undefined behavior.
